# PHP - How can I display an image coming from the different directory without using the absolute path?

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path, subdirectory, base-tag

I just wanna ask how can I display an image from a different directory without using absolute path (cause it's not working). Let's take this example:

Lets assume that I have an htdocs folder and I have a folder inside it named `system`, the `system` folder contains 2 folders and 1 `navigations.php` file inside. The first folder named as `images` and it is the storage of the images that would be use in the program, while the second folder named as `files` and it contains 2 different folders, the `phpfiles` and `cssfiles`, so inside the `phpfiles` folder I have a PHP file named `loans.php` that would include the `navigations.php` (I dont have a problem in including the file) in the `navigations.php` I have a code wherein it will retrieve some images on the `images` folder, but when I included it in the `loans.php` the images in the `navigations.php` did not load. I know that there is are issues with the directories because the file `loans.php` located at the sub-directories of the `system` folder. I tried using absolute path `(C:/xampp/htdocs/system/images/image.png)` but It's not working, so an alternative I used `<base>` tag to use it in a relative path but still it is not appearing in the `loans.php` cause it's located on the sub-directories of the `system` folder. What's the best way to fix it?

PS: Nevermind the example, just focus on the situation :)

**-ADDITION (Problem Solved)**

As a solution I created a PHP function that prints a string depending on a number of step backs on a directory to access directories from a different sub directories.

```
function numberOfBack($num){
    $strback = "";
    if ($num == 0){
        return $strback;
    } else {
        for ($x = 1; $x <= $num; $x++){
            $strback.="../";
        }
        return $strback;
    }
}
```

To use this, the string that would be return will be concatenated to the src of the image or PHP file that I'm going to retrieve. Thank you for the hints and answers.

Comment: How do you view this in your browser? LIKE `localhost/system/` ?

Comment: Yea like that, that's why in my `<base>` my href is "/system/"

Comment: This would probably be easier to understand if you would show the folder structure in form of a screenshot or ASCII art in your posting, instead of spreading the information over multiple lines of prose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only accessing `navigations.php` via `loans.php` the solution is to access the relative path of the image from the perspective of `loans.php`.

In this case, based on your description, it seems that the relative path would be: `../images/image.png`.

Comment: According to my understanding all the codes inside the `navigations.php` will merge on the `loans.php` once I included it on the `loans.php`, so as a solution I used a `base` tag to just use a relative paths on my codes. But the problem is on `navigations.php` my base tag is like this, `<base= "\system\">`, therefore I can retrieve it on the navigations.php throught `<img src= "images\image.png">` but in the loans.php (a different file coming from a different directory) it is not working since i need to go back two directories to use the '<base>' tag of the `navigations.php`

Comment: `/system/` is a relative path, so it will assume `/files/system/`, which isn't your intended. `<base>`, from my experience, is best used with an absolute path anyways. However, try to replace your current base with `<base href="../images/">` and see if that helps.

Comment: Well based on my understanding (in which I dont if it's wrong or not) `<base>` tag is used to just disregard the absolute path of the address in the coding and just use relative path on the coding, also I thought that it is commonly used on websites names, website address, the starting name of the site (example: "www.example.com/") to easily retrieve all the files inside the www.example.com, on your explanation, ../images will go back one directory,

Comment: so the path in the base tag would be system/images which is right BUT how if the loans.php is located inside the folders of the folder inside the system in which I need to go back 2 directories first before I can use the `<base>`?

Comment: Hmm, all the uses I've seen use a full path. *shrug* - anyways... Correct me if wrong, but the layout looks like `/system/files/loans.php` which is trying to access `/system/images/image.png`. Again, `base` does not innately assume it is a absolute path, as it accepts both. Therefore as I stated before, `/system/` is assumed as `./system/`. Have you try to change it to `../../system` or simply `../system` (whichever it might be) ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment replying to mine your absolute path should be as followed:

`http://localhost/system/images/image.png`

I am not an xampp expert but I believe it is configured to have apache render that address instead of the actual folder path like `c:/htdocs/system/`

Comment: Yeah it is, it is not actually working on actual folder path, the `localhost` is default in the address that's why is started by `<base>` on the `"/system/"`